# Execute Snowflake Stored Procedure with Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a linked service is up and running from which I was able to run simple queries.

My intention is to encapsulate the majority of the logic of the ETL in a stored procedure, scheduled and executed from Azure Data Factory "Lookup" component.
However, it seems that I'm unable to execute it with the regular `CALL test_snowflake_sp()` that works so well from the workbench.

My stored procedure is comprised of a simple query followed by a "failure"/"success" message, I get the following error message:

> Activity Get Value failed: Failure happened on 'Source' side.   ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcInvalidQueryString,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The following ODBC Query is not valid: 'CALL test_snowflake_sp()'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.GenericOdbcConnectors,'

Unfortunately I don't have a Python access to run it in code.

Has anyone figured it out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, If you are trying to create and run stored procedure then unfortunately snowflake doesnt allow stored procedures. I also ran in same situation then finally i have to write my query logic in python script.

Comment: Snowflake Stored Procedures are now generally available https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures.html - hope this gives you an extra option for your query logic @marc_s

Answer (score 1):

You can call Snowflake stored procs fine from a Lookup using exactly the syntax from your example.  Be sure you grant the Data Factory user "usage" permissions on the proc, and re-grant any time you "create or replace" the proc  ("grant usage on procedure test_snowflake_sp() to role datafactory"  assuming you have created a role for the ADF user).

Comment: This approach worked for me up until recently where I started getting the same error reported by the OP. Has anyone else seen this or possibly know of a solution / workaround?